# Xamarin : Apple watch application crashes

Tags: xamarin

Apple watch application created using Xamarin crashes immediately upon launch. 
Same application built using older Xamarin version works as charm.

**Earlier config used for build -**

Xcode version:  8.2.1 (8C1002)
Xamarin version:  6.1.5 build 0
Xamarin iOS version: 10.2.0.4 (Xamarin Studio Community)
Mono Version: Mono 4.6.0

**Updated Xamarin environment**

Xcode version:  Xcode 8.3.2 (12175)
Xamarin version: 6.3 (build 864) 
Xamarin iOS version: Version: 10.10.0.36 (Xamarin Studio Community)
Mono Version: Mono 5.0.1.1 (2017-02/5077205) (64-bit)

Further hardware details

1. iPhones used - 5s (10.1.1) and 7 (10.3.2)
2. Watch OS versions tried  - 3.1 and 3.2

All below troubleshooting steps are performed

1. Repairing of watch with iPhones
2. Reinstallation of application

Following links are referred -

https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/100306-searching-on-apple-watch-en-crashes-every-time/
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7465291?tstart=0

Any help in this regards is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you followed Xamarin's materials to do troubleshooting? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/watch/deployment/device/#Troubleshooting